# Pandas sum rows between boolean values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sum the values of all the rows (for multiple columns in reality around 50), between the True values of a bool column in a pandas df, and fill the True rows with the sum number. I had a column with names and based on whether the names contained a substring, I made a mask boolean column. Let me give a visual example.

Current df:

| mask | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | 10 | 3 | 5 |
| False | 5 | 2 | 4 |
| True |  |  |  |
| False | 5 | 1 | 10 |
| False | 1 | 7 | 6 |
| False | 8 | 2 | 4 |
| True |  |  |  |

Desired/Target df:

| mask | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | 10 | 3 | 5 |
| False | 5 | 2 | 4 |
| True | **15** | **5** | **9** |
| False | 5 | 1 | 10 |
| False | 1 | 7 | 6 |
| False | 8 | 2 | 4 |
| True | **14** | **10** | **20** |

I made it with for loops iterating through the df (more "classic programming") but it takes forever cause the df usually is millions of lines. I am looking for a way to do this with pandas since it's very fast.

Also I tried this which I found in another post: (though I am not familiar with groupby and transform so I don't actually know what I did)

```
col_list = [x for x in df.columns if 'col' in x]
df[col_list] = df.groupby(df['mask'].cumsum()).transfrom('sum').where(df.mask)
```

But I got an error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str"

(the actual numbers in the dataframe are floats but I used integers in the example just to make things easy)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming empty cells are NaNs, you could use:

```
# start a new group after a True
group = df['mask'].shift(fill_value=False).cumsum()
# get the sum per group transforming all rows
# and fill the NaN of the original dataframe with it
df.combine_first(df.groupby(group).transform('sum'))
```

output:

```
    mask  col1  col2  col3
0  False  10.0   3.0   5.0
1  False   5.0   2.0   4.0
2   True  15.0   5.0   9.0
3  False   5.0   1.0  10.0
4  False   1.0   7.0   6.0
5  False   8.0   2.0   4.0
6   True  14.0  10.0  20.0
```

Comment: They are NaNs indeed when I first load the files, I transformed them to '' for my simplistic solution with the loops. Your solution seems to be working fine! Thank you!! Could you maybe provide a simple explanation of how it works so I can learn the logic behind it?